# Sharepoint 2019 list settings is disbled - can anyone answer how to enable

Tags: javascript, html, css, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

while creating a new record in SharePoint 2019 record is not showing its date and time created

1 - using the admin user account
2 - click on site content
3 - choose list
4 - click on gear settings logo on top right corner
5 - click on list settings

Comment: make sure that user has appropriate permissions for the list

Comment: appreciate your comment

Comment: Muhammad Murad Haider can you please guide me how i can set permissions on sharepoint

Comment: Muhammad Murad Haider - not able to set unique permission on list and inner pages .........it will be great if you please guide me with the same

Comment: sure you can check this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782
make sure your user has appropriate permissions to do so. If possible try using an account that is Site collection admin. create an SP security group with atleast `Edit` rights. Then using site coll admin account you can break permissions inheritance for the list and set unique permissions, and assign permissions to the security group that you just created.

Comment: Once you are able to edit list, you can modify the list view to show `Created` column to show you the created date/time for the record

Comment: Appreciate your valuable comments , In my case I have inner pages which is connected to same site and I want to assign permission for different department users

Comment: do you have list views on pages?

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider I have copied the link location and given the link from index page for other department pages

Comment: Now trying to restrict other user not to access the other department pages